# How to take a screen shot of my text messges?

Tags: screenshots, samsung-droid-charge

I know how to take screenshots on my Droid Charge but everytime I go to take a picture of a text message it always goes to the page before and takes the picture. It is very frustrating. If you know any way to help please reply.

Comment: You're doing it via Back + Home, right?

Answer (score 6):

For my US Cellular Galaxy S running gingerbread, I had the same problem. When trying to screen capture the text conversation by holding the "back" and "power/standby" buttons, it backs up a screen and takes a screen shot of the message board. I found a work-around. Pull up the message thread you wish to capture. Press and hold the back button. Tap the power/standby button (I know, it will capture the message board). While still holding the back button, tap the message thread you wish to capture. The message thread should now pull up. Press the power/standby button again, and *click", you have your screen capture! This is the only way I have found to do this.

Answer (score 3):

If you have root, use the app ShootMe. You just shake it and it takes a screenshot.

If you have a custom ROM that runs off of CyanogenMod (CM) or is based off of CM, then hold down the power button and select the screenshot option.

Answer (score 2):

If you have access to a computer when you're trying to take the screenshots, you could do it the old fashioned way -- **through the Android SDK**. [These instructions](http://www.simplehelp.net/2009/07/21/how-to-take-screenshots-of-your-android-based-phone-from-windows/) are for Windows, but it will be similar for other OSes--just download the appropriate packages.

When I did this, I had to install the "platform tools" package through the SDK package manager, because a necessary package (adb) was not installed by default.

Answer (score -1):

Just hold the home button and the `+` button down (not too long, though).

Comment: What is "the + button"? Do you mean the volume up button or some such? I've never seen an Android device with a "+ button".